# 1151: A conflict exists with definition i in namespace internal

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs3

im new in action scripts and flash, i need some help with this code i couldnt find whats wrong with it, it gives this error:1151: A conflict exists with definition i in namespace internal.(var i:Number = 0;)

```
    stop();

menu_item_group.menu_item._visible = false;
var spacing:Number = 5;
var total:Number = menu_label.length;
var distance_y:Number = menu_item_group.menu_item._height + spacing;
var i:Number = 0;

for( ; i < total; i++ )
{
    menu_item_group.menu_item.duplicateMovieClip("menu_item"+i, i);
    menu_item_group["menu_item"+i]._x = menu_item._x;
    menu_item_group["menu_item"+i]._y = i * distance_y;
    menu_item_group["menu_item"+i].over = true;
    menu_item_group["menu_item"+i].item_text.text = menu_label[i];
    menu_item_group["menu_item"+i].item_url = menu_url[i];

    menu_item_group["menu_item"+i].onRollOver = function() 
    {
        this.over = false;
    }
    menu_item_group["menu_item"+i].onRollOut = menu_item_group["menu_item"+i].onDragOut = function() 
    {
        this.over = true;
    }
    menu_item_group["menu_item"+i].onRelease = function() 
    {
        getURL(this.item_url);
    }
    menu_item_group["menu_item"+i].onEnterFrame = function() 
    {
        if( this.over == true ) this.prevFrame();
        else this.nextFrame();
    }
}
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: You have somewhere else declared variable i (var i:Number = 0)

Answer (score 1):

Check your code. The variable `i` has been declared in the code already.